# Is it done with Local-storage ? or data-binding in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, data-binding, react-redux, local-storage, redux-form

I am new to react and developing the react application,  where I want that user can save his/her selected values on the frontend and later on can also see those values via clicking a button and user can see what values have been selected previously. now the question is how to provide this functionality, I have studied that either it could be done by local-storage or by the data binding concept in react, but I have no clue which one is best to implement in my scenario.

Let me explain to you with the help of a diagram.

[image: (The first Image with Indicator Generation)This is the main page of my React Application, under the section of "Question & Indicator" there is a thing called Associated Indicator, these are the values which user have select itself on the Frontend side.]

[image: (The second image with detailed user-controls)This is the page where all the user-controls are defined, here user can select the values and at the end when user clicked "Associate" it will be associated and the values have been shown under the section of Associated Indicators, from that user when clicking any of the associated indicators it will show all the values selected by user on front end]

(The first Image with Indicator Generation)This is the main page of my React Application, under the section of "Question & Indicator" there is a thing called Associated Indicator, these are the values which user have select itself on the Frontend side.

(The second image with detailed user-controls) This is the page where all the user-controls are defined, here user can select the values and at the end when user clicked "Associate" it will be associated and the values have been shown under the section of Associated Indicators, from that user when clicking any of the associated indicators it will show all the values selected by user on front end.

Cheers.

Comment: Its better you use a state managament library like redux to do the same, so that it resides inside the app itself,
if you wish for a more persistent one use local storage

Answer (score 0):

Preserving data in a web app is not related to React -or any other front end technology specifically.

Data binding is a concept on how to update your views when certain data changes, and it is not related at all to how data should be saved. But related to how modern front end technologies like react and angular render your components.

You can save data in a web app using different methods, each one is suitable for certain use cases - and so you should use the one that suits you.

For example you can use any of the following:

Cookies: old way of saving data on the front end, can stay infinitely but can also be deleted if the user decided to delete them or clear data from his browser. Cookies Get send to the server-side with each request done with the browser, has limitations with size.

IndexedDB: This one is literally like a database inside the browser, really fast when querying data, also has bigger Size limitations than both Cookies, and LocalStorage. However, this is a really low level API. Won't recommend to use it, unless you really need its features. Can also stay infinitely, and can also be deleted by user.

LocalStorage: New browser API to persist data, much more easier to handle than Cookies And IndexedDB, Can stay infinitely, but can also be deleted by the user. Has bigger size limits than Cookies, but less than IndexedDb.

SessionStorage: Data saved for each tab, and data cleared when page session ends.

Finally If You want data that persist for forever and the user can't delete it, you have to do your own solution in the backend.